# Bootstrap, inline inputs have smaller gap when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

In a modal:
For some reason When I dynamically add a li with two input fields using `jquery append` the spacing of the first `li` (which was already there) has a bigger gap in between the two `inputs` then the rest that are added dynamically.

After checking the developer tools in Chrome, I see that they all have the same padding, margins and borders. From a CSS point of view I can't see a reason why there would be a larger gap in the first one.

[image]

```
<div class="modal-body">
<ul id="add-groups-list">
    <li class="add-group-item">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Group Name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Spots Available" />
    </li>
</ul>
<p><a href="#" id="add-group-in-modal" class="btn btn-small">+</a></p>
</div>
```

in a backbone view I do this:

```
addGroupInModal: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.$el.find("#add-groups-list").append('<li class="add-group-item"><input type="text" placeholder="Group Name" /><input type="text" placeholder="Spots Available" /></li>');
    },
```

Here is some CSS:

```
#add-groups-list{
  list-style: none;
}

.add-group-item input{
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: What I wound up doing is turning the individual list items into a template. So I didn't have to repeat myself with the HTML and so I didn't wind up with white space issues. Since I am using Backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the white space, add a text node with 1 space in between the 2 inputs, or do not indent your HTML code.

```
this.$el.find("#add-groups-list").append('<li class="add-group-item"><input type="text" placeholder="Group Name" /> <input type="text" placeholder="Spots Available" /></li>');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Antti says, the problem is that the whitespace between the `input` elements is being rendered. But if you want to keep the HTML a little more readable, you can also solve this with CSS by just floating the inputs:

```
#add-groups-list {
  list-style: none;
}

.add-group-item input {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

And then add Bootstrap's `clearfix` class to the `li` elements for good measure.

Another way to solve it would be setting `font-size` on the parent elements (the `li`s) to 0. But I prefer floating the inputs.

http://jsfiddle.net/MY7zY/7/